# Ruby, unique hashes in array based on multiple fields

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'd like to get back an array of hashes based on sport and type combination

I've got the following array:

```
[
    { sport: "football", type: 11, other_key: 5 }, 
    { sport: "football", type: 12, othey_key: 100  },
    { sport: "football", type: 11, othey_key: 700  },
    { sport: "basketball", type: 11, othey_key: 200 },
    { sport: "basketball", type: 11, othey_key: 500 }
]
```

I'd like to get back:

```
[
    { sport: "football", type: 11, other_key: 5 }, 
    { sport: "football", type: 12, othey_key: 100  },
    { sport: "basketball", type: 11, othey_key: 200 },
]
```

I tried to use (pseudocode):

```
[{}, {}, {}].uniq { |m| m.sport and m.type }
```

I know I can create such array with loops, I'm quite new to ruby and I'm curious if there's a better (more elegant) way to do it.

Comment: Yes, `uniq` with a block is the way to go, but here's another way: `arr.group_by { |h| [h[:sport],h[:type]] }.values.map(&:first)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to generate an array to `uniq` by.

```
sports.uniq{ |s| s.values_at(:sport, :type) }
```

Comment: Just a tiny correction: `uniq` is passing in each value to the block, so that's actually a `Hash` in this case and it would be calling [`Hash#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). Just be careful if you have an array of things other than hashes or arrays.

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to build some sort of key with the sport and type, like so:

```
arr.uniq{ |m| "#{m[:sport]}-#{m[:type]}" }
```

The way [uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) works is that it uses the return value of the block to compare elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'pp'

data = [
    { sport: "football", type: 11, other_key: 5 }, 
    { sport: "football", type: 12, othey_key: 100  },
    { sport: "football", type: 11, othey_key: 700  },
    { sport: "basketball", type: 11, othey_key: 200 },
    { sport: "basketball", type: 11, othey_key: 500 }
]

results = data.uniq do |hash|
  [hash[:sport], hash[:type]]
end

pp results

--output:--
[{:sport=>"football", :type=>11, :other_key=>5},
 {:sport=>"football", :type=>12, :othey_key=>100},
 {:sport=>"basketball", :type=>11, :othey_key=>200}]
```